# Redirect URI not valid with Outlook MAIL REST API

Tags: azure, redirect, oauth-2.0, outlook, coldfusion

### Pre Info

I have a working ColdFusion application (web-based) with a fully Google Oauth2 verification process implemented. This works good and I can retrieve e-mails en post commands. Now I want to do the same with Microsoft's Outlook.

---

### Problem

When I try to do a HTTP POST request to the token URL then I get a response that my redirect URI is not valid because it's not the same as the one I used to get the code.

---

### What works

I can retrieve the code by doing a GET request to the Oauth endpoint. I've added a redirect URI in the azure portal (multiple URI) When I call this URL then I get a login screen from outlook and after that I'm **successfully** redirected back to my application. So I guess the redirect URI is correct and it's all working.

When I try to get the token with the received code then I get the redirect error. I've absolutely no idea how it comes up with the fact that these URIs are not the same. I've triple checked everything but cannot find anything wrong.

---

### Error

This is the error I'm getting:
"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS70000: The provided value for the 'redirect_uri' is not valid. The value must exactly match the redirect URI used to obtain the authorization code.

I've tried different kinds of formats. Dash on the end or no dash. But the fact stays that the redirect URL is working for the earlier step. So why not with this one?

When I play around with it then I also get messages like "Code expired", so I know it's working properly. I've played around with options in the azure portal. I followed the Oauth2 outlook playground. But still I cannot get past this message. How can I figure out what is going on here?

### REQUEST

I've tried different ways to do the request. The most simple one is this one:

```
cfhttp(method="POST", charset="utf-8", url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token", result="result") {
cfhttpparam(name="Content-Type", type="header", value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
cfhttpparam(name="grant_type", type="formfield", value="authorization_code");
cfhttpparam(name="code", type="formfield", value="M090efafb-1ce6-1d54-fda7-e48f57c33cba");
cfhttpparam(name="scope", type="formfield", value="openid offline_access profile https://outlook.office.com/mail.read https://outlook.office.com/mail.read.shared https://outlook.office.com/mail.readwrite https://outlook.office.com/mail.readwrite.shared https://outlook.office.com/mail.send https://outlook.office.com/mail.send.shared");
cfhttpparam(name="redirect_uri", type="formfield", value="#URLencode('https://bizz.bmk-is.nl/')#");
cfhttpparam(name="client_id", type="formfield", value="cdee5a0a-a409-4c41-9572-726c5bdbe93e");
cfhttpparam(name="client_secret", type="formfield", value="[HIDDEN VALUE]");
            }
```

### ## NEW EDIT ##

I will post some more information here. First of all, this is the get I'm using:

```
response_url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize";
response_url = "#response_url#?response_type=code";
response_url = "#response_url#&client_id=cdee5a0a-a409-4c41-9572-726c5bdbe93e";
response_url = "#response_url#&redirect_url=#URLencode('https://bizz.bmk-is.nl/')#";
response_url = "#response_url#&scope=openid offline_access profile";
response_url = "#response_url# https://outlook.office.com/mail.read";
response_url = "#response_url# https://outlook.office.com/mail.read.shared";
response_url = "#response_url# https://outlook.office.com/mail.readwrite";
response_url = "#response_url# https://outlook.office.com/mail.readwrite.shared";
response_url = "#response_url# https://outlook.office.com/mail.send";
response_url = "#response_url# https://outlook.office.com/mail.send.shared&prompt=login";
```

This is the error I'm getting now:
"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADSTS90102: 'redirect_uri' value must be a valid absolute Uri.

Comment: Please edit your question and include details about the requests (both GET and POST).

Comment: @GauravMantri Hey, thanks for the quick response. I added an example of a POST request done in coldfusion.

Comment: The `GET` request is still missing in your edit (the one that is requested by the client browser). It's important that the `redirect_uri` in both, the GET and the POST request, is identical.

Comment: @Alex I know that the GET is missing because I know he was about to ask if the get/post redirect_uri are the same. Well I tried it a hundred times on different ways so believe me when I say: those url's are the same. I must be something else. I also stated that the first step of the Oauth process went as expected, so the first redirect goes correctly.

Comment: See, the GET request snippet was the one that would have solved the riddle. Always include as much info as possible and never assume "it can't be that".

Comment: @Alex Yea you're absolutely right about that. I was more focused on looking at the url itself. But thanks for the info, always good to have a second pair of eyes looking at a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OMG I found it! I was searching around and playing around with the redirect uri's, when I noticed that in the get I called it "redirect url" and in the post "redirect uri". Changed that to uri and now it's working! Super nice. Still weird that I don't get an error in the get that redirect url is nothing, but hey I'm glad it's working.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to URL encode your 'redirect_uri'.

Here is an example from the MS Getting started with Outlook REST page.  Notice the encoding on the URI:

```
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=<CLIENT ID>&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F&response_type=code&scope=openid+Mail.Read
```

And then getting the AccessToken:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=authorization_code&code=AwABAAAA...cZZ6IgAA&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F&client_id=<CLIENT ID>&client_secret=<CLIENT SECRET>
```

Comment: `cfhttpparam` automatically encodes its value. But OP didn't show us the GET request yet.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I already tried a encoder myself only on the POST, now I tried it again but it comes with a different error (seen it a couple of times). The error is as following: 'redirect_uri' value must be a valid absolute Uri. I will try some more stuff, and I will also post my GET in my question. I really.. REALLY want to get this to work. I can even give you some compensation if it works.